# Parent element loses hover on select of a dropdown

Tags: css, google-chrome, select, hover

I get a strange behavior by Google Chrome 33 (Ubuntu).

I have a div element, which gets resized and repositioned on hover. Underlying there is a `<select>` element. When I try to select an option the `:hover` state of the parent div is lost.

I can't reproduce this in Firefox or Opera.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QHhmV/1/)

[image: demo]

Comment: Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m (Windows 7) everything is alright.
Guess it's Ubuntu specific.

Comment: Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152 on Mac works okay.

Comment: Strange, i can not reproduce it since i don't have a Ubuntu vm here. But just a blind guess, try to append the `:focus` selector as well: http://jsfiddle.net/QHhmV/2/ would be interesting to know if that makes a difference

Comment: Thanks for your replies, this is strange that this is Ubuntu specific! @NicoO Unfortunately the `:focus` state does not affect it.

Comment: @DanLee Try this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/QHhmV/3/). I added onchange event to get focus.

Comment: @Mr_Green See above, does not work.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78994

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a known Chromium issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78994

[My workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/QHhmV/4/) requires a hover CSS class + Javascript, as CSS parent selectors aren't a thing:

```
$('select').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('hovered');
}).on('blur', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, after all these years your answer still helped me!

Comment: @TimGerhard Glad to hear :)