# IE11 :hover effect stops working when hovering over selects

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my css hover on IE.

To simplify; I basically have a container div which will when hovered show a small div inside with some `<select>` tags inside (see code below). This setup works fine on all major browsers except (who guessed it) on Internet Explorer (11 and probably lower versions too).

The hover works fine, but as soon as you **try to select a `<option>`** from the two `<select>` tags, the :hover will for some reason no longer work and the div disappears.

Try this example in chrome / firefox etc to see the desired result & try then again in IE11 to see the problem.

```css
.containerDiv {
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.containerDiv:hover .someDiv {
  left:0;
}

.someDiv {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerDiv">
  <div class="hoverMe">
    Hover Me
    <div class="someDiv">
      <h3>
        Hi, I'm SomeDiv
      </h3>
      <select>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>
</select>
      <br><br>
      <select>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>
</select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see this for a workarround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530270/parent-element-loses-hover-on-select-of-a-dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comment you could use something like this as a workarround for this issue:

```
$("select").on("focus", function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("hovered");
}).on("blur", function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("hovered");
});
```

Then apply `.yourParentElement.hovered` to the same rules as `.yourParentElement:hover`:

```
.yourParentElement:hover, .yourParentElement.hovered { /* some css rules */}
```